# Load more JSON data into listview on scrolling, using Volley library

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

I tried to implement the code given in the tutorial below to create an endless list.
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews

But I'm not sure how to implement the customLoadMoreDataFromApi(int page) method referred to in the tutorial. My JSON Request and parsing method is below. I need help in adding the parameter 'page' to the request and appending new set of data to the list.

```
    Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
    if (entry != null) {
        // fetch the data from cache
        try {
            String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
            try {
                parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    } else {
        // making fresh volley request and getting json
        JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "InitialResponse: " + response.toString());
                if (response != null) {
                    parseJsonFeed(response);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        // Adding request to volley request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
    }

    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

        for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
            item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

            // Image might be null sometimes
            String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("image");
            item.setImge(image);
            item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
            item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
            item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

            // url might be null sometimes
            String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("url");
            item.setUrl(feedUrl);

            feedItems.add(item);
        }


        // notify data changes to list adapater
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to use the offset value and add it as a parameter to your API request to retrieve paginated data and deserialize API response and then construct new objects to append to the adapter. Pl Help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you a different solution:

1. Create a custom component that extends ListView
2. Custom adapter
3. Custom listener

..

```
   public class EndlessListView extends ListView implements OnScrollListener {

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}
}
```

..

Now you have to overwrite onScroll to implement the logic:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    if (getAdapter() == null)
        return ;

    if (getAdapter().getCount() == 0)
        return ;

    int l = visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem;
    if (l >= totalItemCount && !isLoading) {
        // It is time to add new data. We call the listener
        this.addFooterView(footer);
        isLoading = true;
        listener.loadData();
    }
}
```

where the listener is defined as:

```
public static interface EndlessListener {
    public void loadData() ;
}
```

Now when the even is fired and the loadData is called in this method you update the listview content retrieving it remotely.
Hope it helps you. If you like more information i wrote a [post about it](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/10/android-listview-endless-adapter.html). 
Give a look.